# Where does this site define a background image on its header?

Tags: html, css, background

I was looking at the source code for [this website](http://soldnomore.org) and I'm stumped as to how the background image on the header is implemented. Using Chrome's inspection tools, I can find nothing inside the ``banner-area` div, and no image styles on the div of any sort. How do they do it?

Edit: As @makadlcik pointed out, it is the `page-header` div that has the background. But then how did they create the `banner-area` div that appears to be inside the image? I realize that it is impossible for HTML to be *inside* an image but Chrome's devtools make it appear as such.

Comment: Downvoters, why? My question shows research effort and is clear.

Comment: I’m not sure why you find it impossible. The `page-header-wrapper` `div` is a _`div`_, not an `img` element. You can put `div`s inside other `div`s. There’s nothing impossible about it.

Comment: What I meant in that sentence was that you can't put HTML inside an `<img />`. But I understand what you're saying about the divs being on top, and it makes sense to me now. If you post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `background-image` property of `page-header-wrapper` div.

[image: screenshot of chrome devtools]

link of the background image: http://static.squarespace.com/static/51c50433e4b05645eb845ef5/t/51e592d9e4b047a5486b868d/1373999833147/Web%207.jpg

---

You probably meant that you cannot put an html tag inside an `<img>` element, because it is a single tag, but that is not this situation. They created a div as a parent with background image. A div is a pair tag, so it can contain a child.

Comment: Alright, thanks. But how did they create the smaller div with id banner-area *inside* the image?

Comment: @VirtualDXS not sure what is the problem, when you have the background-image, you can have anything over it: https://jsfiddle.net/t4xntuz1/ .

Comment: Yeah I figured that out from @Xufox's comment. I was just confusing different concepts. Thanks.

Comment: @VirtualDXS I updated the answer to match the updated question.